# Is it possible to use South without recording the migrations?

Tags: django, django-south

Let's say, I start with an app:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    f = models.CharField(...)
```

This structure is recorded in `migrations/0001_initial.py`.

I add 2 fields:

```
    g = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    h = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I create a migration:

```
manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

`migrations/0002_add_field_g_add_field_h.py`

Soon I remove the `g field. If I run schemamigration, there will be the 3rd migration. But all this was development process, and when I push to DVCS server for the rest of my team, I don't need to send all the test migrations that I made. I need only the end product. How can this be done in South?

Comment: second's answer will work, but why go through all this trouble? It seems cleaner and less error-prone to just use south normally and push all of the migrations back to your team.

Comment: @Spike: because these schemas are useless garbage. I want a workflow like in Mercurial: I save data only when I want it. With South it is like you commit each time you save a file.

Comment: gotcha. Guess it's just a personal preference thing :)

Comment: Well, it's timesink. If you make it automatic, you're foced to commit garbage. Otherwise you need to memorize things, and will forget them sometimes. We've had all this with code before VCS came around: save files to a .zip, copy them to the hosting, etc. VCS learned to keep files and understand what we need to do (Git can shoot you in the foot sometimes, but I use Mercurial :). They can handle sub-repositories. Hg is so smart that it can work with Git subrepos. I think, learning to work with migrations is the next logical step. I want PC work for me, not the other way.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I can see where you're coming from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible but a bit of a faff. in particular you need to make sure all your test migrations are reversible

when you are done testing, you can roll back all your test migrations, and then delete the migration files and re-run `./manage schemamigration`